# Delete items with duplicate keys in alist in Lisp

Tags: lisp, elisp, common-lisp, associative-array, duplicates

Suppose I have a large alist, where there are multiple items with the same key but same or different values:

```
'((a . 1)
  (b . 2)
  (a . 3)
  (a . 4)
  (b . 5)
  (b . 6))
```

Usually when you use alists, you access items with `assoc`, which returns the first matching item in a list and ignores the rest. So the idiomatic way to treat alists is that every time you want to replace an item in alist with a new value for an old key, you just add a new dotted pair and ignore the old one. So no matter how many duplicates you have, `assoc` will ignore them. You work via alist API and ignore the implementation details, so to speak. But what if I honestly want to have an alist with all duplicates physically removed? With only the newest dotted pairs remaining in the list, so the above alist would become `'((a . 1) (b . 2))`?

Any solution for both Common Lisp or Emacs Lisp is acceptable.

Comment: The question is tagged with both [tag:elisp] and [tag:common-lisp].  The answer provided in the "duplicate" question only covers Emacs Lisp.  If you aren't concerned with [tag:common-lisp], it should be removed from the tags.

Comment: For Common Lisp, use `remove-duplicates` or `delete-duplicates` with the keyword arguments `:key #'car :from-end T`, see also: http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rm_dup.htm